# How to capture multiple succeeding words on regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi I created a regex that would detect a question where it is starting with
"What is _____?"

```
(?:what is ([a-zA-Z]+)\?)
```

It works only if the word after "What is" is only one word.

> "What is dinner"  // returns true

for example, but if I add another word in my question

> what is breakfast and lunch? // returns false

It returns `false`, what do I need to add for the succeeding words in my question to return true in my regex pattern?

Comment: `/what is [a-z]+(?:\W+[a-z]+)*\?/gi`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex: `(?:[Ww]hat is (([a-zA-Z]+\s*)+)\s*\?)`

In this `\1` will return the part after "What is".

Try [here](https://regex101.com/r/dH4zR8/1).

`(([a-zA-Z]+\s*)+)` will match multiple space separated words.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks! If I would like to match the "What is" word not being case sensitive what will i need to change in my regex?

Comment: @CrisRyanTan Do you want the `w` to be case sensitive? I mean in the above regex it is already case insensitive. To make case sensitive use `w` or `W` in place of `[Ww]` whatever you want.

Comment: oh my bad. i meant case-insensitive. it is working out great now. thanks!

Comment: This `(?:[Ww]hat is (([a-zA-Z]+\s*)+)\s*\?)` regex is EXTREMELY poor. Have a look [how it can easily cause a time out issue](https://regex101.com/r/fV6sH4/1). And now see [`/what is ([a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*)\?/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/fV6sH4/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you please post your regex as the answer with an explanation. I want to understand the issue. Thanks. :)

Comment: Actually, Pranav has already posted this regex (without a capturing group though). The point is that you should never rely on `A(C+D*)+B` like patterns (as `D*` may match an empty string, and then the whole pattern behaves as `(C+)+` in between other subpatterns causing backtracking issue). And I always repeat this, but few people listen: shorter does not mean more efficient when it comes to regex - and it really matters EVEN with "small", "easy" patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match space separated words, for that use

```
/what is [a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*\?/i
```

---

[Regex explanation here.](https://regex101.com/r/eD1xL0/2)

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks! I tested it out at regex101 and it works out great.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many variations of regexes for such case. 
Consider the following simple one:

```
var str = "what is breakfast and lunch?",
    hasQuestion = /what is \w+?.+?$/.test(str);
    // . - matches any character except new line 
console.log(hasQuestion);  // true
```